# AES Decryption Error

Tags: java, encryption, aes

Encryption is working optimally it seems the  text is appearing to be encrypted when looking at the file. Im stuck on the decryption process though and having errors:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3521)"

Im calling the method using this:

```
char [] password;
byte [] encrypted;
decrypt(input, new File(outFile),encrypted,password);
```

// decrypt method

```
public void decrypt(File inputFile, File outputFile , byte [] encrypted, char [] password) throws Exception {

    byte[] iv = Arrays.copyOfRange(encrypted, 0, IV_SIZE_IN_BITS / 8);
     byte[] ciphertext = Arrays.copyOfRange(encrypted, iv.length, encrypted.length);



      Cipher cipher = initCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, password,iv);
       FileOutputStream fos = null;
       CipherInputStream cis = null;
       FileInputStream fis = null;
       try {
           fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
           cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
           fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
           byte[] data = new byte[1024];
           int read = cis.read(data);
           while (read != -1) {
           fos.write(data, 0, read);
           read = cis.read(data);
           System.out.println(new String(data, "UTF-8").trim());
           }
       } finally {
           cis.close();
           fos.close();
           fis.close();
       }
}
```

NEW---------

```
 private static final String KEY_DERIVATION_FUNCTION = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256";
  private static final String ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM    = "AES";
  private static final String TRANSFORMATION          = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";
  private static final String GENERATOR_ALGORITHM     = "SHA1PRNG";

  private static final int KEY_SIZE_IN_BITS = 128;
  private static final int  IV_SIZE_IN_BITS = 128;
  private static final int TAG_SIZE_IN_BITS = 128;
  private static final int ITERATION_COUNT  = 200_000;





private static Cipher initCipher(int mode,char [] password, byte[] iv) {

    GCMParameterSpec gcmSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(TAG_SIZE_IN_BITS, iv);

    SecretKey key = deriveKey(password, iv);
    try {

      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
      cipher.init(mode, key, gcmSpec);
      return cipher;
    }

    catch (
      NoSuchAlgorithmException |
      NoSuchPaddingException   |
      InvalidKeyException      |
      InvalidAlgorithmParameterException ex
    ) {
      throw new AssertionError(ex);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not specifying the encryption algorithm, mode or padding with:

```
Cipher cipher = initCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, password,iv);
```

It seems it is defaulting to n algorithm other than AES, what algorithm do you want to use?

Always specify exactly what you need, do not rely on defaults. I suspect that in your case you want algorithm: AES, mode: CBC, padding: PKCS#7 (sometimes specified PKCS#5). But these must exactly match the encryption. Also supply the key and iv with exact lengths desired, for key length use 128-bits, 192-bits or 256-bits (16-bytes 24-byte or 32-bytes) and for the iv 16-bytes.

The error `javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException`means:

> This exception is thrown when a Cipher operating in an AEAD mode (such as GCM/CCM) is unable to verify the supplied authentication tag.

Comment: I am using "AES/GCM/NoPadding"; at the moment ... just trying a few things as i type this.. I am going to post my 'initcipher in the post^ under "NEW"

Answer (score 1):

If you're really calling your decryption method with this code:

```
char [] password;
byte [] encrypted;
decrypt(input, new File(outFile),encrypted,password);
```

then your `password` and `encrypted` variables have not been initialized, and are both null, hence the `NullPointerException`.  You have to set your variables to refer to actual arrays containing the encryped data and the password.

Comment: Am I not using this appropriately?   byte[] encrypted = "water".getBytes();
  char[] password = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };

Comment: I am now getting a tag exception Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
 at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.getMoreData(CipherInputStream.java:115)
 at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:233)

Answer (score 0):

The error `java.lang.NullPointerException` from the Java Docs [Java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_copyofrange_short.htm):

> **NullPointerException** -- If original is null.

Check the actual data length vs the requested range. Also verify the values of `IV_SIZE_IN_BITS`, `iv.length` and `encrypted.length`.

Comment: thanks for the reply zaph. I have corrected this problem* I am just working on the other exception now above in the reply^